# p-adic series converging to two different values for two different p-adic norms

Tags: normed-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

I am aware of the definition of p-adic numbers, and the notion of convergence that applies.

The task given to me is as follows:

> Find an explicit sequence of natural numbers that converges to $3$ in $Q_3$ and $5$ in $Q_5$.

This is what I know : the norms above are not equivalent, and the proof is by considering the sequence $3^m$, for example, which converges in one norm and not the other.

I am still unable to even think of a sequence that converges in both norms. I was wondering if $15^k$ does the job, but I'm not sure.

My last sub-approach is, to find something that converges to zero in $Q_3$ but not in $Q_5$ (any non-zero value will do, e.g. $1$), and  vice-versa, and then scale both by weights and add them  to get the desired series.

Comment: The series $a_k=15^k$ converges to 0 because both  $v_3(a_k)=k$ and $v_5(a_k)=k$ both of which tend to infinity as $k\to \infty$.

Comment: @Ravi Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just Chinese Remainder Theorem. You want, for each $n$, an integer $z_n$ satisfying the pair of simultaneous congruences $z_n\equiv3\pmod{3^n}$ and $z_n\equiv5\pmod{5^n}$. For $n=1$, of course $0$ works, but for $n=2$, you are in effect finding a number satisfying a congruence modulo $9\cdot25=225$.

Comment: I would like to know how the problem  stated in your answer is equivalent to the above problem. Once I get to know, then since I know the above procedure, I will be able to get an answer. Thank you for your reply. Furthermore, if this is the case, then I get the answer to an  extension question given as well : find another sequence satisfying the above and converging to $7$ in $Q_7$ also.

Comment: The sequence $\{z_n\}$ is, by construction, convergent to $3$ in $\Bbb Z_3$ and to $5$ in $\Bbb Z_5$. I admit that I did not tell you an algorithm for finding the numbers $z_n$, any more than @LStU gave you analgorithm for his numbers $a_n$.

Comment: Convergence happens, since $|z_n - 3|_3$ and $|z_n - 5|_5$ both go to zero by construction, ok I see. As for construction, don't you have a formula for $z_n$ by the usual proof of the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Sorry, I always solve explicit CRT problems by inspection.

Comment: That's fine, I know that I can solve these congruences. Thank you for your help. Your answer is more helpful than the other, simple because it doesn't stop at two primes, it's clear(-er than the other) to see how it can be extended. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5):

How about getting a sequence $(a_n)$ converging to $0$ $3$-adically,
and to $1$ $5$-adically? Then $3+2a_n$ does the job. To do the first, how
about $a_n=3^nb_n$ with $b_n\in \Bbb Z$? If we could ensure that $a_n\equiv1\pmod{5^n}$ that might be good...

Comment: Certainly such $b_n$ exists. Here, if $c_n = 3+2a_n$, then $c_n-c_m = 2(a_n-a_m) = 2{3^nb_n - 3^mb_m}$. It is clear that the 3-adic and 5-adic norms of the difference converge to $0$ by choice of $b_n$, so that the sequence is Cauchy in both norms. How can I see what the limits are in $Q_3$ and $Q_5$ are $0$ and $1$? I think I know, but it would be great if you can clarify this.

Comment: I like this answer better than mine. For a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of the type you suggest, start with $81$, which is close to zero $3$-adically, and $\equiv1\pmod5$. Then take successive fifth powers of $81$, that is $81^5$, $81^{25}$, $81^{125}$, etc. These converge to $1$ in the $5$-adic topology.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, I understand (after some time) how this works. Honestly, I think you need some exposure to the subject before coming up with this. It's phenomenal.

Comment: Well, I am an *old* hand at the subject.